# Can tests (for which only parameters differ) be shared by multiple robot files?

Tags: robotframework

First: The company I'm working for is sadly only supporting an ancient version of Robot Framework: 3.0.4

We have 2 robot test-sets for a code-generator tool: 1 for c-files and 1 for c++-files.
Both test-sets have a number of tests which are either exactly the same or just differ on 1 or 2 parameter-values.

If it were keywords we just would implement them in a 'common.robot' file which is then used as "Resource".
But is it also possible to define complete tests in this way and 'automagically' execute the tests in the robot-files which use the resource?

In a mock-implementation this is what we would like to do:

resource.robot:

```
Common testcase
    Given <situation>
    When <trigger-action> with    ${extension}
    Then <assert-action>
```

c.robot:

```
Resource    resource.robot

*** Variables ***
${extension}    .c

# Automagically executes 'Common testcase' with '.c'
```

cpp.robot:

```
Resource    resource.robot

*** Variables ***
${extension}    .cpp

# Automagically executes 'Common testcase' with '.cpp'
```

Is something like this possible in robot? (And then especially in the version we can use: 3.0.4)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot import a file that contains tests as a resource. What maybe is closes to what you want is using [test templates](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates).

So you can create a test template keyword in your common resource and then run this template against different parameters in any suite file.

common.robot:

```
*** Keywords ***
Test Template - Test Name
    [Arguments]    ${arg}
    Log    ${arg}
```

c.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    common.robot


*** Test Cases ***
Test For C
    [Template]    Test Template - Test Name
    arg=C
```

cpp.robot:

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    common.robot


*** Test Cases ***
Test For CPP
    [Template]    Test Template - Test Name
    arg=CPP
```

Comment: Since I had to switch to another more urgent story it can be a while before I can check this out and mark the solution as accepted (or not).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use test template, using data-driven style should be easier in your case.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template    Login with invalid credentials should fail

*** Test Cases ***                USERNAME         PASSWORD
Invalid User Name                 invalid          ${VALID PASSWORD}
Invalid Password                  ${VALID USER}    invalid
Invalid User Name and Password    invalid          invalid
Empty User Name                   ${EMPTY}         ${VALID PASSWORD}
Empty Password                    ${VALID USER}    ${EMPTY}
Empty User Name and Password      ${EMPTY}         ${EMPTY}
```

Here is how your tests might look like

```
*** Settings ***
Test Template    Some Keyword

*** Test Cases ***
Some Test With C      .c
Some Test With CPP    .cpp

*** Keywords ***
Some Keyword
    [Arguments]    ${arg}
    Some Keyword 1    ${arg}
    Some Keyword 2
    Some Keyword 3
```